# События в дочернем виджете. Qt

Tags: qt, инспекция-кода

Есть виджет (Кастомный TextWidget, который наследует QWidget). Могу по клику мыши создавать кастомные QTextEdit-ы. Устанавливаю `setEnabled(false)` и хочу, если мышка внутри TextEdit, менять `shape` курсора. Переопределил `mouseMoveEvent` в классе TextWidget(кастомном) и еще переопределил `eventFilter`, чтобы , если `QObject` - это TextEdit , а событие-движение мыши, передавать на обработку аргумент `event` в TextEdit-овый `mouseMoveEvent`.

```css
bool TextWidget::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (obj != this && event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove && cursor().shape() != Qt::SizeAllCursor)
    {
        QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
        mouseEvent->setLocalPos(static_cast<QWidget*>(obj)->pos() + mouseEvent->pos());
        mouseMoveEvent(mouseEvent);
        
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

Может есть способ лучше? Может лучше будет так, переопределить уже в TextEdit и не трогать TextWidget (Или нет)?

```css
void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
  if (!isEnabled())
    parentWidget()->mouseMoveEvent(event); //И тут тоже поработать с event->pos()
  else
  {
        QTextEdit::mouseMoveEvent(event);

  }
  
}
```

Все работает. Просто не уверен с правильностью выбора.